# How do I add custom tab in the user profile page?

Tags: users, 8, routes

I need to add a custom tab in user profile page. I defined my route like below:

**mymodule.routing.yml**

```
mymodule.account:
path: '/user/{user}/custom'
defaults: 
  _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleUserSettingsForm'
  _title: 'Custom Settings'
  user: \d+
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

**mymodule.links.task.yml**

```
mymodule.account:
  title: Mymodule Settings
  route_name: mymodule.account
  base_route: entity.user.canonical
```

**mymodule.links.menu.yml**

```
mymodule.account:
  title: My module Settings
  parent: entity.user.canonical
  route_name: mymodule.account
```

Then after clear cache tab is appearing in the profile page. But when I open the url **/user/1/custom** I see the page not found message.

Comment: user: \d+ should go under requirements - make that change, clear all cache, see if you still get page not found.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is in the `mymodule.routing.yml` file, the big problem is the place of `user: \d+`, this line must be under the `requirements:` section, the other problem is the indentation. So the final code should be:

```
mymodule.account:
  path: '/user/{user}/custom'
  defaults: 
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleUserSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Custom Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    user: \d+
```

And of course you need the form class definition in `src/Form/MyModuleUserSettingsForm.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class MyModuleUserSettingsForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule\Form
 */
class MyModuleUserSettingsForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'simple_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#size' => 64,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  }

}
```

And a `mymodule.info.yml` file to complete your module (in this case named mymodule)

```
name: My Module
type: module
description: 'My module'
core: 8.x
package: Custom
```

**Reference:**
[Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes)

Comment: Interesting that the [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes) does not mention the key `user:` nor where it should go... Perhaps the docs need to be improved/edited? or did I miss something?

Comment: nvm, I see, it's under **_entity_access:** and they used node as an example there, hence why my CTRL + F "user:" did not find anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to load a form using a route.  You can either load up a callback that loads a form and returns it as part of the build array, or you can load up the form directly by setting the _form parameter under defaults.

You can search the codebase to find working examples, copy them into your mymodule.routing.yml, edit them to your needs and then rebuild the cache.

**Loading form from callback:**

There's a working example in the contact module:

/core/modules/contact/contact.routing.yml

```
entity.user.contact_form:
  path: '/user/{user}/contact'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Contact'
    _controller: '\Drupal\contact\Controller\ContactController::contactPersonalPage'
  requirements:
    _access_contact_personal_tab: 'TRUE'
    user: \d+
```

Then in /core/modules/contact/src/Controller/ContactController.php

you can see an example of how to load a form in the callback:

```
  public function contactPersonalPage(UserInterface $user) {
    // Do not continue if the user does not have an email address configured.
    if (!$user->getEmail()) {
      throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $message = $this->entityManager()->getStorage('contact_message')->create(array(
      'contact_form' => 'personal',
      'recipient' => $user->id(),
    ));

    $form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($message);
    $form['#title'] = $this->t('Contact @username', array('@username' => $user->getDisplayName()));
    $form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user.permissions';
    return $form;
  }
```

**Loading form directly from the route:**

If you would like to load the form directly using the _form default, there's an example in the shortcut module at /core/modules/shortcut/shortcut.routing.yml

```
shortcut.set_switch:
  path: '/user/{user}/shortcuts'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\shortcut\Form\SwitchShortcutSet'
    _title: 'Shortcuts'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: 'Drupal\shortcut\Form\SwitchShortcutSet::checkAccess'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    user: \d+
```

In this case, the user is passed in as a parameter to the form, see 
/core/modules/shortcut/src/Form/SwitchShortcutSet.php

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, UserInterface $user = NULL) {
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things I can spot off hand...

You've got EVERYTHING named mymodule.account. I'd diversify that a bit. Consider going with this for the tasks page:

```
mymodule.account_tab:
  title: Mymodule Settings
  route_name: mymodule.account
  base_route: entity.user.canonical
```

I also do not believe you need anything in the menu either for this.

Between those two, you should be good to go! Feel free to reach out to me directly if you can't figure this out because I --JUST-- got this to work on my D8 port of Apply For Role!

Answer (score 1):

In modulename.routing.yml you have to pass user argument like below

```
profile.user_information:
  path: '/user/{user}/profile'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\profile\Form\UserInformation'
    _title: 'UserInformation'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    user: \d+
```

and in modulename.links.task.yml you have the code like below

```
profile.user_information:
  title: User profile
  route_name: profile.user_information
  base_route: entity.user.canonical
```